# how to select all ID fields inside ko.observableArray([])

Tags: knockout.js

I have a list like this as ko.observableArray([])

[image]

And I just need to have all ID fields inside  it

I coded this but I ran into some errors

```
 self.ApprovePersonAttendanceDataList().ID()
```

and

```
 self.ApprovePersonAttendanceDataList()['ID']
```

And I tried below code but I got ab empty array

```
self.ApprovePersonAttendanceDataList().map(x => x.ID)
```

Comment: `self.ApprovePersonAttendanceDataList().map(x => x.ID)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Comment: @VLAZ I think so ,maybe there are two ways,map and pluck function would help but I don't know the difference

Comment: `pluck` is also an option, if you have Underscore: `_.pluck(self.ApprovePersonAttendanceDataList(), "ID")`. You can also use `_.map` as `_.map(self.ApprovePersonAttendanceDataList(), "ID")` would do the same.

Comment: This link http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html could help.  You could use `ko.utils.arrayMap()`.

Answer (score 0):

but this one worked! don't know exactly why.

```
self.ApprovePersonAttendanceDataList().map(({ ID }) => ID))
```